# Why react-native-cli giving errors?

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

I recently installed react native cli globally. When i tried to start a project using `react-native init projectname` or `npx react-native init projectname` it started downloading packages and creating the project. After completion it gave this error

```
    cli.init(root, projectname);
      ^

typeerror: cli.init is not a function
    at run (c:\users\showbi\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:302:7)
    at createproject (c:\users\showbi\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:249:3)
    at init (c:\users\showbi\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:200:5)
    at object.<anonymous> (c:\users\showbi\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:153:7)
    at module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at object.module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at function.module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at function.executeuserentrypoint [as runmain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

What is causing this problem?

Comment: The issue is by having some globally installed Yarn/NPM packages.  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34055#issuecomment-1165887713

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: cli.init is not a function for react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768245/typeerror-cli-init-is-not-a-function-for-react-native)

Answer (score 19):

Probably you are have and using old react-native-cli, try to:

`npm uninstall -g react-native-cli` or `yarn global remove react-native-cli`

and then run `npx react-native init projectname` again.

Comment: The key for me was understanding that I need to ditch `react-native-cli` completely, and just let the `npx react-native` do the work

Answer (score 8):

That is error is from the new version 0.69.0
You can use `npx react-native init ProjectName --version 0.68.2` and then upgrade to v 0.69 later.

Answer (score 5):

The quick way out is

```
npx react-native init ProjectName --version 0.68.2
```

Because that error is from the new version 0.69.0 You can use upgrade to 0.69.0 later.

But the longer route is below:

Need to clean global environments with following commands:

```
yarn global remove react-native

yarn global remove react-native-cli

npm uninstall -g react-native

npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

check that nothing related to react-native presents in these lists:

```
yarn global list

npm -g list
install new react-native global

npm install -g react-native-cli
npm install -g react-native
```

then you can run:

```
npx react-native init ProjectName
```

Comment: As mentioned in the docs, it is recommended to remove existing global react-native-cli packages.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete react native cli from globally and manually delete folder at:
c:\users\showbi\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli

It is work for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

remove react-native CLI globally
(npm uninstall -g react-native-cli)
and reinstall your app
(npx react-native init app name)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Replacing npx react-native with npx react-native@latest solved it for me.