# TypeError: cli.init is not a function for react native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, typeerror, apple-m1

While running npx react-native init appName in MacBook air M1 chip

```
TypeError: cli.init is not a function
at run (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:302:7)
at createProject (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:249:3)
at init (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:200:5)
at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:153:7)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1166:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:834:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Comment: Same issue occurring in Windows 10. Using react-native-cli to init a project

Answer (score 180):

install new react-native global

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

install new react-native global

```
npm install -g react-native-cli

npm install -g react-native
```

and create project again

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

Comment: > if you previously installed a global react-native-cli package, please remove it as it may cause unexpected issues.

Comment: When I created a new React Native Project my Ios/Anroid folders were not created, which was head scratching because I've done this before  a few times already.  Your solution was a huge help and should be on top due  to how easy the issue was to solve with your help thank you.

Comment: The key for me was understanding that I need to ditch `react-native-cli` completely, and just let the `npx react-native` do the work

Comment: This worked for me. Tnx

Answer (score 49):

Need to clean global environments with following commands:

```
yarn global remove react-native

yarn global remove react-native-cli

npm uninstall -g react-native

npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

check that nothing related to react-native presents in these lists:

```
yarn global list

npm -g list
```

install new react-native global

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
npm install -g react-native
```

then you can run:

```
npx react-native init ProjectName
```

Comment: It didn't work- Did it work for you?

Comment: It worked- Didn't it work for you?

Comment: It didn't work too. Needed this one: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34055#issuecomment-1164390603

Answer (score 17):

> This happened because you have an old version of react native, So you
> need to remove the react native version globally and install it again.
>
> Steps to fix your problem:

***if you use Yarn:***

First Step:
Check the Global installation list:

```
yarn global list
```

> if you found react-native and react-native-cli so go to the next step
> and remove them globally

Second Step:

```
yarn global remove react-native
yarn global remove react-native-cli
```

Third Step:
Install them again

```
yarn global add react-native
yarn global add react-native-cli
```

***if you use NPM:***

First Step:
Check the Global installation list:

```
npm -g list
```

> if you found react-native and react-native-cli so go to the next step
> and remove them globally

Second Step:

```
npm uninstall -g react-native
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

Third Step:
Install them again

```
npm install -g react-native
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

> Note:  Delete the old project you create, then create it again. Every
> thing will go fine.

Answer (score 10):

That is error is from the new version 0.69.0
You can use `npx react-native init ProjectName --version 0.68.2` and then upgrade to v 0.69 later.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answer (score 4):

If you previously installed a global react-native-cli package, please remove it as it may cause unexpected issues:

**npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli**

React Native has a built-in command line interface, which you can use to generate a new project. You can access it without installing anything globally using npx, which ships with Node.js. Let's create a new React Native project called "AwesomeProject":

**npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject**

This is not necessary if you are integrating React Native into an existing application, if you "ejected" from Expo, or if you're adding Android support to an existing React Native project (see Integration with Existing Apps). You can also use a third-party CLI to init your React Native app, such as Ignite CLI.

Comment: I vote +1 for this answer. Since the latest react-native (0.71.3) no longer requires react-native-cli@2.0.0. Being said, remove the cli and npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject works in my case. My environment: MacOS 10.14.6 Node v.14.19.0 NPM 6.14.16

Answer (score 4):

I think latest stable version is 0.68.2, so create project at this level using command given below

`npx react-native init ProjectName --version 0.68.2`

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me.

Strangely,
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli
npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject
did not work.

Answer (score 3):

If you previously installed a global react-native-cli package, please remove it as it may cause unexpected issues:

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli
```

Link [Here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup#:~:text=If%20you%20previously%20installed%20a%20global%20react%2Dnative%2Dcli%20package%2C%20please%20remove%20it%20as%20it%20may%20cause%20unexpected%20issues%3A)

Answer (score 2):

Should run:

`yarn global list` or `npm global list`

And uninstall all cli's of the react-native in list, after run:

```
yarn global add @react-native-community/cli
```

Answer (score 1):

Do->
`yarn global remove react-native-cli && npm uninstall -g react-native-cli`

Then->
`yarn global add @react-native-community/cli`
or
`npm install -g react-native-cli`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to clear the issue by uninstalling the cli and only installing react-native

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
npm install -g react-native
```

then

```
react-native init ProjectName
```

I am using

```
react-native -v
10.1.3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already installed react native globally, uninstall it by:
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli

Then install it again by:
npm install -g react-native-cli

Then you can create your new project by the following command:
npx react-native init <project_name>

Answer (score 1):

```
yarn add react-native --exact
```

I re-installed react native with --exact and this fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

remove react native cli using this command

> npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
> then
> npm install -g react-native

no need for it now as.

React Native has a built-in command line interface, which you can use to generate a new project.

Check [reactnative.dev](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you previously installed a global react-native-cli package, please remove it as it may cause unexpected issues. You can run the following command:

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli
```

or

```
yarn global remove react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli
```

Follow the Reference: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Answer (score 0):

I tried every solution above mentioned none of them didn't worked actually except this(npx react-native init ProjectName --version 0.68.2)

But finally i fixed my issue by deleting node modules from my user folder .[image: Go to user/username/and delete node modules and old projects or any package.json files.]

then now run :- npx react-native@latest init projectname

Answer (score 0):

npx react-native init AwesomeProject --version 0.68.2 solved my problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't remember that I installed it with brew and that was the problem, it must be deleted from there as well

First uninstall:

> ```
> brew remove react-native-cli
> npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
> npm uninstall -g react-native
> ```

Next step, install:

> ```
> npm install -g react-native
> npm install -g react-native-cli
> ```

Answer (score -2):

Try with this latest command.

```
npx react-native@latest init ProjectName
```

Worked for me!