# Why does cli.init fail when creating react-native project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I try running `npx react-native init AwesomeProject`
for Create a new project. I have tested it before, but it created the project without error, but it doesn't work anymore. I had to reinstall nodejs.

**Node.js v17.7.1**

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:302
  cli.init(root, projectName);
      ^

TypeError: cli.init is not a function
    at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:302:7)
    at createProject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:249:3)
    at init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:200:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:153:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Node.js v17.7.1
```

Comment: You might have react-native-cli installed locally, which could cause issues as mentioned [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup). Try uninstalling react-native-cli using command ```npm uninstall -g react-native-cli``` and see if that resolves your issue

Comment: @sushrut619 I don't have react-native-cli installed, when I type ``react-native-cli -v`` , there is nothing, but when I type ``react-native -v ``:  ``react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: n/a - not inside a React Native project directory``

Comment: CLI is command line interface. When you type ```react-native -v``` you are using the react-native-cli. It says in the output the version as 2.0.1. Have you tried uninstalling it globally using the command in my previous comment? What errors do you get when you try to init project after uninstalling react-native-cli ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: cli.init is not a function for react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768245/typeerror-cli-init-is-not-a-function-for-react-native)

Answer (score 1):

That is error is from the new version 0.69.0 You can use npx react-native init ProjectName --version 0.68.2 and then upgrade to v 0.69 later.

Answer (score 0):

**Check for the react-native present:**

yarn global list

npm -g list

**Uninstall the react-native & react-native-cli:**

yarn global remove react-native

yarn global remove react-native-cli

npm uninstall -g react-native

npm uninstall -g react-native-cli

**Check and confirm the react-native was uninstalled:**

yarn global list

npm -g list

**Install the react-native & react-native-cli:**

npm install -g react-native-cli
npm install -g react-native