# TypeError: cli.init is not a function when npx react-native init

Tags: android, ios, react-native

After upgrading React Native from 0.68.2 to 0.70.1 on MacOS Monterrey M1, `npx react-native init my-prom` started throwing error:

```
/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:302
  cli.init(root, projectName);
      ^

TypeError: cli.init is not a function
    at run (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:302:7)
    at createProject (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:249:3)
    at init (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:200:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:153:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Node.js v18.7.0
```

`npm -g list` shows `react-native-cli 2.0.1` was installed globally. Remove `react-native-cli` and install it again global didn't fix the problem. React Native was installed locally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: cli.init is not a function for react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768245/typeerror-cli-init-is-not-a-function-for-react-native)

Comment: I saw this post before posting and not exactly. Ended up with reinstall the react-native after removing react-native-cli.

Comment: The key for me was understanding that I need to ditch `react-native-cli` completely, and just let the `npx react-native` do the work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
yarn add react-native --exact
```

This should be able to fix your problem, don't know exactly why though!

Comment: Scavenged throughout the internet, and this simple command was the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

First install React Native CLI and framework:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli react-native
```

Then create a new React Native project:

```
npx react-native init ProjectName
```