# When I open a new react-native project I always get this error

Tags: react-native, npx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYv6U.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWyq6.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the images as text. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/68587)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: cli.init is not a function for react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768245/typeerror-cli-init-is-not-a-function-for-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed react-native-cli globally uninstall using

```
npm uninstall -g react-native
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

and then install again using

```
npm uninstall -g react-native

npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

This error is specifically for 0.69.0 version. You can also do

```
npx react-native init ProjectName --version="0.68.2"
```